# Can regular languages be Turing complete?

Tags: regular-languages, programming-languages, turing-completeness

I was reading about [Iota and Jot](http://www.nyu.edu/projects/barker/Iota/) and found this section confusing:

> Unlike Iota, where the syntactic tree for a string can branch either on the left or on the right, Jot syntax is uniformly left-branching. As a result, Iota is strictly context-free, but Jot is a regular language.

My understanding is that both Iota and Jot are Turing complete. But apparently, one is context-free, and the other is regular! Surely regular languages can't be Turing complete?

Comment: Note that a language describing a turing machine can be trivially written in a regular language, for example i={0,1,-1},b={end of input} (i+bi+bi)+b(i+) describes a non-empty set of rules followed by a non-empty input. Or, rather, you can interpret it like that if you have an interpreter, which, as the answers mention, is a separate concept to the class of the language.

Comment: @Cubic: for that matter, Turing machines can be numbered such that every number represents exactly one machine (i.e. they're countable), and those numbers can be expressed in unary notation. I never properly studied this stuff, so I have to labour over the definitions, but I reckon `1*0` is a regular language ;-) Albeit not a very friendly programming language either for the programmer or the compiler-writer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In short, the answer is yes.

But you're mixing two completely unrelated meanings of the term "language" (yes, this is confusing):

- A set of strings. "Context-free language" means "a set of strings which can be recognized using a context-free grammar".
- A way of specifying a computation. "Turing-complete language" means "a way of specifying programs in which the Turing machine can be specified".

Note that you can talk about "the C++ language" from two completely unrelated viewpoints, using the two unrelated meanings of the word "language":

- C++ as a set of strings which are legal according to the C++ grammar
- C++ as a way of specifying programs.

The traits of "the C++ language" from these two viewpoints are unrelated.

More examples to help you separate these concepts:

- The expression "[a-z]+@[a-z].[a-z]" describes a set of strings recognizable by finite automata, i.e. a regular language. However, it's just that - a set of strings: is not a way of specifying programs (unless you ascribe a way to interpret each such string as a program), so it does not make sense to talk about whether or not it is Turing-complete.
- The language of flowcharts is a way of specifying programs; depending on the particular flavor of flowcharts, it may or may not be Turing-complete. However, flowcharts aren't strings, so it makes absolutely no sense to talk about flowcharts in the sense "language as a set of strings".

Comment: I would add that `(([a-z][0-9]*)*[A-Z][0-9]*([a-z][0-9]*)*->([a-zA-Z][0-9]*)*)*` is a regular language that is able to describe grammar of any language of class 0

Comment: Also note that this is possible because we encode any Turing Machine as a binary string, and can make sure every binary string represents a Turing Machine. So the obviously regular language of $\{0,1\}^*$ can have Turing Complete semantics attached to it.

Answer (score 11):

While the set of legal programs in Jot is regular, Jot itself is Turing-complete. That means that each computable function can be expressed in Jot. We can even come up with a language in which all binary strings are legal, but the language itself is Turing complete (exercise). You're confusing syntax and semantics.

By the way, context-free languages are also (probably) not NP-complete, since they have a polynomial time parsing algorithm.

Answer (score 9):

Syntax alone (as encoded in syntax trees) of modern programming languages is far from everything they do. In fact, the *formal* languages defined by the set of all programs in a given language that compile without error are [rarely even context-free](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9196/1546).

Static and dynamic semantics factor into the equation. They are invisible in the syntax tree but determine if a piece of code is actually a program and what it computes.
Bottom-line, the context-free resp. regular formal language which is defined by "syntax" gives an *overapproximation* of the programming language.

Now to answer your question: yes, it's possible. Consider, for instance, any [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) of Turing machines; you get the "programming language" of all natural numbers, each representing a TM. Granted, it's not a nice language to program in, but it's certainly a Turing-complete language which is regular -- trivial, even.

Answer (score 5):

1. A programming language is *Turing-complete* if 
   it is expressive enough to specify every function computable by Turing machines. 
   Here we are discussing 
   *the power of languages specified **in** the programming languages*.
   E.g. it is not difficult to write an interpreter for Turing machines in Python,
   so Python is a Turing-complete programming language.
2. *The syntax of a programming language*, i.e. 
   the set of strings corresponding to valid programs in the programming language,
   is itself a language. 
   E.g. consider the set of all possible Python programs. 
   The syntax of a programming language can be *context-sensitive*, *context-free*,  *regular*, etc. 
   We are interested in the difficulty of checking that 
   a given string is a valid program in the programming language
   (this is done by compilers/interpreters).
   When we say the syntax of a programming language is context-free 
   it means that there is a context-free grammar for its syntax and implies that  there is push-down automata for checking the validity of programs,

Note that the simplicity of the syntax of a programming language does not imply 
a restriction on the computational power of the programs 
specified in that programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. You see, as the accepted answer states, a grammar is independent of its meaning. In Chomsky's own words:

> I think we are forced to conclude that a grammar is autonomous and
>   independent of meaning...
>
> Chomsky, Syntactic Structures (1956)

If a grammar can produce sufficient sentences to describe all things that can be computed then we can arbitrarily assign computational meaning to its sentences - one for each thing that can be computed.

As for a real concrete example, the popular language `whitespace` has a regular grammar and perhaps even `x86 assembly languages` (needs verification).

Comment: I don't think that passage means that Go's grammar is a regular language in the formal sense; I think it just means that the grammar is _not irregular_, i.e. consistent. If Go's syntax were actually a regular language in the Chomsky hierarchy, it would be incapable of generating e.g. balanced, nested parentheses.

Comment: Yes, there is recursion in Go's grammar. Updating post.